# Media server that supports FLAC files with tags

Tags: audio, streaming, dlna, upnp, flac

I recently bought a Raumfeld audio streaming system and I am now looking for a media server to store my collection using the FLAC format.

My first idea was to use my Fritz Box 7390 router as media server. You can simply connect a USB drive and configure it as a media server. This basically works, but the tag information for FLAC files is not analyzed, which is also mentioned on a site by the manufacturer (http://en.avm.de/nc/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7390/knowledge-base/publication/show/1074_File-formats-supported-by-the-Media-Server/). Without the tag information the Raumfeld app cannot identify compilations and displays therefore every track as a single album. (With a MP3 collection on the USB drive there is not problem.)

When I connect a USB disk directly to a Raumfeld device (e.g. Raumfeld One M), I don't have that problem. So the root cause, I assume, is not wrong meta information (tags), nor a bug in the Raumfeld app, but that the Fritz Box media server is not sending that information.

But, I dont't want to connect a USB drive directly to my Raumfeld device, I would like to install a proper media server. I am looking for working real life examples. I already read about the MinimServer (http://minimserver.com/index.html), which sounds promising.

Does anybody now of a media server that support FLAC files AND tags? Maybe even in combination with a Raumfeld device?

Comment: Simon, if you're open to use a "custom ROM" on your Fritz, you can integrate [MediaTomb](http://mediatomb.cc/) with the open source [Freetz](http://freetz.org/) firmware (I'm using my 7390 with Freetz, as I did with all other FBs before – no Fritz without Freetz for me ;), it's very stable and reliable – and it's much more flexible and customizable. Integrating MediaTomb might take some effort (due to its size, it must be setup as "external application"), but according to several reports it's doable.

Comment: Thank you @Izzy for your tip. I will look into MediaTomb  and Freetz. But since my Fritz Box is provided by my ISP, I prefer a solution without modifying the FB itself.

Comment: It might be possible to get MediaTomb running on the FB without "freetzing" it. Their site [reports](http://mediatomb.cc/pages/devices): *We also offer precompiled static binaries that can be installed as an addon to the existing NAS firmware*, and list a.o. the 7270 as supported. A German [article on HIFI-Forum](http://www.hifi-forum.de/viewthread-258-886.html) might prove helpful as well. If you got that running, be encouraged to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) :)

Comment: Thank you @Izzy for the links. I will study them and maybe go for that solution or try to setup a MinimServer on a Raspberry Pi. Either solution needs time, which I currently don't have a lot. But, I will for sure update this question or answer it once I found a solution that works for me.